# Access violation in huge array?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Here is my code:

```
constexpr auto array_size = 50000000; 
double M[array_size][2][20]= { };


int main()
{
    for (int n = 0; n < array_size; n++)
        printf("%d %f\n",n, M[n][0][0]);
}
```

When n printed to about 150, this program crashed.

I also see abnormal value in M[90], it is like 386721638216381263812386113....

a super long number.

Comment: Probably some bss section limit. In any case it's bad to have such big data in static format, use std::vector.

Comment: `M` is going to take up nearly 15 gigabytes. I'm not really sure if you should want that baked into your executable.

Comment: I need a very large array, they were all calculated in runtime (init as 0).

Comment: @LindaLambie That's true for [`scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) but not for [`printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). For variadic arguments, in general, `float` is always converted to `double` when passed as argument. (See [Variadic arguments - Default conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)). Please, note that `scanf()` requires addresses while `printf()` requires values to handle floating points.

Comment: What is your platform? Windows or Linux? 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Windows 10 64 bit, visual studio 2019, set to debug, x64.

Comment: Did you tried to use dynamic allocation (`new` and `try catch` bad alloc) or something like `std::vector<>`?

Comment: no, trying vector now. ( only know array before )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio doesn't normally allow you to allocate arrays larger than `0x7fffffff` bytes with the error:

```
error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes
```

I guess there is a compiler bug that prevents the detection of the oversize array in this case and the array is not initialised correctly.

Using `std::vector` instead and allocating the array on the heap works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

constexpr auto array_size = 50000000;

int main()
{
    std::vector < std::vector< std::vector< double > > > M( array_size, std::vector< std::vector< double > >( 2, std::vector< double >( 20 ) ) );
    for (int n = 0; n < array_size; n++)
        printf("%d %f\n", n, M[n][0][0]);
}
```

Note that this will however use more than the minimum required 16GB of memory, if you really need to have all the data in memory at once a single dimensional vector may be more efficient.

Comment: My PC is 16GB RAM, Windows 10, I tested this method(replace array as vector in my program), Windows eventually hang ( used up all 16GB memory ), maybe it still working, but screen become black, no response ...etc. Will Linux handle this issue better?

Comment: Yes Linux should be better as it doesn't allocate memory for pages containing only zeros, note that when you start putting values into the vector you'd still run into the same issue. If you only have 16GB of ram then trying to manipulate 16GB in memory is always going to run into problems you need to look into another approach such as memory mapped files

Comment: I did test the above on my machine which also has 16GB of memory and after some swap thrashing it did work eventually