# How deepmind reduce the calculation for Q values for Atari games?

Tags: sql, c, tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

We know q-learning need tons of calculations:

[The huge amount of states in q-learning calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234489/the-huge-amount-of-states-in-q-learning-calculation)

For a gaming AI, it needs much more q-values than OX game, GO game.

How this is to be done to calculate these large amounts of q-values?

Thanks.

Comment: It builds a game-tree iteratively one node at the time. Look into Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS).

Comment: For me, it is really doesn't look like an easy procedure. https://storage.googleapis.com/deepmind-media/alphago/AlphaGoNaturePaper.pdf I need someone to explain it in detail.

Comment: Can you explain how MCTS reduce the calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MCTS didn't actually reduce any calculation for q-values.

For a very simple Atari gaming AI, it needs much more than 3^(19x19) q values.

Check the deep q network, that solved your problem.

> We could represent our Q-function with a neural network, that takes
>   the state (four game screens) and action as input and outputs the
>   corresponding Q-value. Alternatively we could take only game screens
>   as input and output the Q-value for each possible action. This
>   approach has the advantage, that if we want to perform a Q-value
>   update or pick the action with highest Q-value, we only have to do one
>   forward pass through the network and have all Q-values for all actions
>   immediately available.

https://neuro.cs.ut.ee/demystifying-deep-reinforcement-learning/

Comment: Google 'deep q network' you will get tons of results.